# Put object3d in the altitude location destination position

Tags: swift, augmented-reality, scenekit, core-location, arkit

How can set node (3d object) in the floor with `ARKit` and `CoreLocation`?

I want when my distance is less than 20 meters. My object on the ground using altitude. I use CoreLocation and SceneKit.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`CoreLocation` framework gives you an `altitude` instance property, measured in meters:

```
var altitude: CLLocationDistance { get }
```

Also you can use a `floor` property that's a logical floor of the building in which the user is located:

```
@NSCopying var floor: CLFloor? { get }
```

Comment: sorry ,but I know ,I have altitude , My problem is I don't know how to use it.

Comment: Please publish you code and thorough description what you wanna get.